# dosemu doesn't load MS-DOS Kernel

Tags: manjaro, emulation

I would like to run MS-DOS 2.0 , that has been republished as free software, in dosemu.

I followed the instructions at www.dosemu.org and added

```
$_hdimage = "/home/absmeier/workbench/DOS/VM/DOSC"
```

to the dosemu.conf , but the kernel doesnt boot

Comment: That link is to the website, not to the instructions you say you've used. Please [edit] that so it's easy to find a copy of what you did follow.

Answer (score 4):

`_hdimage` needs to point to a disk image, not a directory. So you’d have to prepare a disk image containing MS-DOS 2.0.

If you try doing that though you’ll discover that the binaries and source code released by Microsoft are incomplete. They correspond (more or less) to the basic kit provided to OEMs, so you’d also have to do the work expected of OEMs at the time: develop an implementation of `FDISK` (or re-use an existing one, compatible with DOS 2), and more importantly, provide the missing files needed to build `IO.SYS`, which is needed to boot.

There’s more information on the missing pieces on [OS/2 Museum](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/ms-dos-1-1-2-0-source-code-released/comment-page-1/).